# Window.atob in javascript providing different decoded value to Base 64 Decoder Java

Tags: java, base64, decode

I have the following base 64 encoded string:

```
e4EdYQYDTpC7sN0K87elHA==
```

In Window.Atob in javascript it provides me with {aN»°Ý ó·¥ however when running the below code in Java it gives me

```
{�aN����
�

String encodedString = "e4EdYQYDTpC7sN0K87elHA==";
Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
byte[] decodedByte = decoder.decode(encodedString);
String decodedString = new String(decodedByte);
System.out.println(decodedString);
```

As you can see the output is extended ascii but I cannot seem to replicate the results of Window.atob in java.

The Byte output from Java is:

```
123
-127
29
97
6
3
78
-112
-69
-80
-35
10
-13
-73
-91
28
```

While the output should be:

```
123 194 129 029 097 006 003 078 194 144 194 187 194 176 195 157 032 195 179 194 183 194 165 028
```

Any ideas on what needs to be done in order to replicate the result.

Comment: Why the javascript tag? Javascript is **not** the same or closely related to Java and seems to be out of context on this question.

Comment: I have removed it however included it on the basis of using Window.atob which seems to be giving me desired results

Comment: Try this code. `byte[] message = "e4EdYQYDTpC7sN0K87elHA==".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        String encodedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(message);` by replacing the first line of your code.